# How to add an option page to custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

As the title says, I have not found any function to add an option page to a particular custom post type.

I would like to keep the option page related to a custom post type grouped together in its own panel, instead of adding it to the "Setting" panel, for example.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and as the pass

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME',....);
```

Comment: Lovely, kudos for you ;)